# YUI MenuBar positioned behind a ASP.NET Silverlight Control

Tags: asp.net, silverlight, yui, yui-menu

Using the YUI Menubar, when the items drop down they appear behind a ASP.NET Silverlight Control. I am not using YUI layout.

I've already tried setting the z-index:99 and the position:relative for in menubar css, as well as setting the div's z-index:-1 and position:relative.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the ASP.NET Silverlight Control's **Windowless** attribute to **true** eliminates this issue.
*Note: Doing this will enable the browser's selected-dashed-border that appears whenever the Silverlight Control is in focus...*

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to try the configuration variable "iframe: true" so as to force iframe shims to be used on the page.  Iframe shims can often solve z-index issues with plugins on browsers (I've used this variable to fix inline PDFs with Adobe Reader).

The configuration variable can be set when creating the Menu:

```
var oMenu = new YAHOO.widget.Menu("basicmenu", { iframe: true });
```

Comment: The configuration variable on what?